# Error: Wireless interface (wlp2s0) IP configuration was unavailable on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

I have a problem connecting to my wi-fi extender (TP-Link WA850RE). I configured it so that its SSID is different from the "original" router. The SSID is not the problem.

When I configure its Ipv6 to link-local, the laptop actually connects to the extender, but there is no internet. When I switch Ipv6 to Automatic, it can't connect anymore and a notification pops up saying `Wireless interface (wlp2s0) IP configuration was unavailable` . I really need some help.

Here is the output of `ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:ec:c5:48:18:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.17/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 85553sec preferred_lft 85553sec
    inet6 fe80::9f1c:2108:b04a:93a0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx00e04c68003e: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:00:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This is the output of `iwconfig` when laptop is connected to the "original" router.

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VodafoneCasa.salamon.sal"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 14:14:59:56:DA:4D   
          Bit Rate=234 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:39   Missed beacon:0

enx00e04c68003e  no wireless extensions.
```

Here the output of `iwconfig` with laptop connected to the extender and Ipv6 set on link-local.

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VodafoneCasa.salamon.sal_ext"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: AC:84:C6:5D:00:9F   
          Bit Rate=28.9 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3   Missed beacon:0

enx00e04c68003e  no wireless extensions.
```

Here the output of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: 68:ec:c5:48:18:45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.1.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:150 memory:dcb00000-dcb01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@4:1.3
       logical name: enx00e04c68003e
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:00:3e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=half firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

Here the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1e.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

output of `dpkg -l wpasupplicant | grep ii`

```
ii  wpasupplicant  2:2.9-1ubuntu4.3 amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

output of `ls -al /run/NetworkManager/system-connections`

```
total 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 mag  6 17:43  . drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 140 mag  6 17:51  .. -rw------- 1 root root 348 mag  6 17:43 'Wired connection 1.nmconnection'
```

Output of `ls -al /etc/netplan`

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 mag  5 21:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 143 root root 12288 mag  6 10:05 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   104 mag  5 20:18 01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Output of `ip -4 route show`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.17 metric 600
```

Output of `ip -6 route show`

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
```

No output for `systemctl is-enabled systemd-networkd.service && networkctl status disabled`

Output for `systemctl is-enabled systemd-resolved.service && resolvectl status enabled`

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 3 (enx00e04c68003e)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 2 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
          DNS Domain: ~.         
                      station
```

Output for `systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlp2s0.service && wpa_cli status`

```
● wpa_supplicant@wlp2s0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: For more convenient discussion this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123920/discussion-on-question-by-enrico223-error-wireless-interface-wlp2s0-ip-config).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you solved your problem and posted and the answer. Please don't put SOLVED, FIXED, RESOLVED etc in the question title. The green check mark ✅ next to your answer is sufficient in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to make it work. I had to to configure manually the DNS server and the DHCP client on the Ipv4 section, and set the Ipv6 to `Link-local`. I found those information logging into my windows machine sending `ipconfig` to the prompt and by looking at the details of the wi-fi connection, also in windows.